# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router> ---- ReactJS form with Yup+Formik+Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, formik, yup

I'm trying to make a simple redirect after a React form be sent to the server and accepted. To do this Redirect I'm trying to render a `<Redirect/>` component after the request to the server done well.

But after the response of the server the message "Usuário criado com sucesso!" (that means "User created") shows up to the screen, but when comes to the `render()` method this error is shown "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Redirect>` outside a `<Router>`"

I've tried to put the function "handleOnSubmit" outside the return() but the same error appeared. If anyone has another way to do that redirect I would be so thankful.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ErrorMessage, Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup'

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import api from '../../services/Api';

import Navbar from '../../components/NavBar'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer'
import './styles2.css' 
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const Register: React.FC = () => {

    const [created, setCreated] = useState("");
    const [notCreated, setNotCreated] = useState("");
    const [errorEmail, setErroremail] = useState("");


    const validations = yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário").min(5),
        email: yup.string().email("*Email inválido").min(3, "Email não é grande o suficiente").required("*Campo necessário"),
        number: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário").min(11, "Número inválido"),
        password: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário").min(8, "*Senha deve ter no mínimo 8 caracteres"),
        role: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário"),
        interactian_code: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário"),
        repeat_password: yup.string().required("*Campo necessário").oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Senhas não conferem')
    });

    useEffect(() => {

    },[created])

    useEffect(() => {

    },[errorEmail]);
    


    return (

        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="flex-box1 container-box1">
                <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={async (values:any)=>{
                    {
                        const response = await api.post('/interactians', {
                            headers:{
                                content_type: "application/json"
                            },
                            name: values.name,
                            email: values.email,
                            tel: values.number,
                            password: values.password, 
                            interactian_code: values.interactian_code,
                            role: values.role
                        }).then((res) => {
                            console.log(res.status);
                            if(res.status === 201){
                                setErroremail("");
                                setCreated("Usuário criado com sucesso!");
                                setTimeout(()=>{
                                    render(
                                        <Redirect to="/"/>
                                    )
                                }, 2000)
                            }else{
                                setNotCreated("")
                            }
                
                        }).catch((error)=>{
                            console.log(`Esse é o erro -----> ${error.status}`)
                
                            switch(error.message){
                                case "Request failed with status code 406":
                                    setErroremail("*Email em uso!");
                                        break;
                            }
                        })
                
                        console.log(response)
                
                    }
                    }
                } validationSchema={validations}>
                    <Form className="content-box1">
                            <h1 className="color">Criar Conta</h1>
                            <h4 className="color">Começar com conta existente</h4>
                            <button className="logue-fc">Logue com Facebook</button>
                            <br></br>
                            <button className="logue-gg">Logue com Twitter</button>
                            <br></br>
                            <b>
                                <p className="ou">OU</p>
                            </b>

                        <Field className="caixas" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="name" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>
                            <span>{errorEmail}</span>
                        <Field className="caixas" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="email" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>

                        <Field className="caixas" name="number"  type="text" placeholder="Número de celular"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="number" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>

                        <Field className="caixas" as="select" name="role">
                            <option value="presidente">Presidente</option>
                            <option value="diretor_de_projetos">Diretor de Projetos</option>
                            <option value="diretor_de_serviços_internos">Diretor de Serviços Internos</option>
                            <option value="diretor_de_imagem_pública">Diretor de Imagem Pública</option>
                            <option value="administrador_do_site">Administrador do site</option>
                            <option value="rotariano_patrocinador">Rotariano patrocinador</option>
                            <option value="associado">Associado</option>

                        </Field>
                        <ErrorMessage name="role" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>

                        <Field className="caixas" name="interactian_code" type="password" placeholder="Código Interactiano"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="interactian_code" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>
                    

                        <Field className="caixas" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="password" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>

                        <Field className="caixas" name="repeat_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirmar senha"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name="repeat_password" render={(e) => <span className="caixas-error">{e}</span> }/>

                        <button type="submit" className="btnesse">
                            Cadastrar
                        </button>
                        <h1 className="created-message">{created}</h1>
                        <h1 className="not-created-message">{notCreated}</h1>

                    </Form>
                </Formik>

            </div>

            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Redirect` component will not work if it is outside of a `BrowserRouter` component.

Your `Redirect` is going to wind up outside of the `BrowserRouter` because of the strange way that you are calling it.  You are not including it in the returned JSX contents of this component.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
```

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  render(
    <Redirect to="/"/>
  )
}, 2000)
```

What you are doing is using the `render()` function that you imported from React Testing Library to insert it into the DOM — why? This function is going to insert the element into the DOM in a new node which is outside of your app and outside of the required `BrowserRouter` provider component.  Per [the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render):

> By default, React Testing Library will create a div and append that div to the document.body and this is where your React component will be rendered.

Here is the document tree that you create by doing this:

```
document
  body
    div id="root" <-- where ReactDOM.render() puts your App
      App
        BrowserRouter
          Route
            Register
    div <-- where React Testing Library puts your Redirect
      Redirect
```

You need to return the `Redirect` **from this component**.

Let's add a state for a `boolean` value `shouldRedirect`.  If this is `false`, we render the form.  If it is `true`, we render the `Redirect`.

```
const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);
```

We will update that state by calling `setShouldRedirect` when we want to execute the `Redirect`.  You could do this in your `useEffect` which depends on `[created]`.  But I'll keep this in the same place you had it, and just change what your `setTimeout` does.

```
setTimeout(() => { 
  setShouldRedirect(true); 
}, 2000);
```

Now we conditionally render the `Redirect` component inside of your `return`.

```
return (
   <>
      {shouldRedirect && <Redirect to="/" />}
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex-box1 container-box1">
....
```

Comment: Could you give me an example with code? I didn't really understand. My component is rendering on a `<Route>` component

My 'route' file:

```
const Routes: React.FC = () => {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
   <Route component={Register} path="/register" exact />
  </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
 )
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at `import { render } from '@testing-library/react';` and `setTimeout(()=>{render(<Redirect to="/"/>)}, 2000)`.  That `Redirect` is not going to be inside your current component.

Comment: I can edit my answer.  Your routes are fine.  It's the `render()` that's the issue.

Comment: Ok I updated with a clearer explanation of what's happening now and some code to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this issue using the ```<Router>``` with ```history``` instead of ```BrowserRouter```. But I tested your solution and this fixed as well.